# Is it true that my AJAX requests aren't necessarily made to my Controller in order?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, t-sql, post, transactions

So I have a basic

```
$.ajax( { url : 'MyController/MyAction', 
          method : 'POST', 
          async: true, 
          .
          . } );
```

that can be called very frequently as it is event-driven. Like it may be called 50 times in 1 second if the user is being obnoxious. It updates values in the database.

My friend told me that it's possible that the updates may be sent to the database in the wrong order. Is this true? This is causing me major cognitive dissonance and I can't sleep tonight.

I should mention that these values being updates in the database are associated with a user. In particular, the `data` is like

```
data : { userId : '21EC2020-3AEA-4069-A2DD-08002B30309D',
         answerId : '69', 
         val : 'd' }
```

where the only values changing in rapid succession are `answerId` and `val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, my understand is "YES. The order is not guaranteed".
You send http request 50 times in 1 second and server save it to DB.
When the network is good and server is strong, it is okay to be saved to DB in order.
But if http sever is busy or network is interrupted, it does not guarantee the data will still always ordered in real happened sequence. Ex, 1 or 2 data order will be exchanged in DB.

My suggestion is : if the order is very critical and the update traffic is heavy, you should add a happen time in http data and save it to DB.
When you select data from DB, you can order by the happen time and it will make sure it has the correct order as event happens to avoid the mis-order caused by server or network busy.